# To disscuss via/by/in voice

Tags: phrase-usage

I know a phrase:

```
to discuss in person
```

If I'd like to speak with person on the phone to discuss a problem using voice, how do I name it:

```
to discuss matters in/by/with voice
```

?

Comment: "To *[talk it over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/talk-sth-over)* by phone" is one natural way of putting it, IMHO.

Comment: "(Let's) talk about it on the phone" or "discuss it on the phone" is also common.

Comment: @CopperKettle Not sure, why haven't you made an answer out of your comment...

Comment: Done, Denis! (0:

Comment: Perhaps you could **converse** with a friend about it.

Comment: @ Denis Kulagin Do you have a knack for speaking on the phone without using your voice? If you practise ventriloquism, then, of course, it is important to clarify how you are going to use the phone. ;)

Comment: @Humbulani Good point, but what if we are talking about video chat or conference call? It's not exactly a phone then, but format "in voice" stays the same.

Comment: Then you could say: "let's have a conference call so that we can discuss this problem or issues",  "let's have a voice chat to discuss it", "let's organize/have webcam-based discussion of these issues", "let's communicate with voice chat/ video chat".

Comment: That's ok, but you can say "Let's meet and discuss this issue in person." It obvious, that if you meet, you are going to discuss problem in person. But you still make additional stress on it. The same with "in voice" is not possible to say, while I want to say to a person, that "I would like to have a conference call to disuss problem in voice. BECAUSE CHATTING IS NOT ENOUGH, in my opinion."

Comment: @ Denis Kulagin Sorry, I don't understand. Would you be kind to formulate your thoughts in other words?

Comment: @Humbulani I'll try. If you say, that you want to meet some person and discuss something in person, then you are reasoning your request: *I want to meet <= BECAUSE <= to discuss issue in person.* The same is with my question: Why would I like to setup a call? Because I can't solve the problem via chat and I think, that discussing it in voice would be better.

Comment: If you say that you want to talk about something on the phone or in voice chat, any sentient being will understand that you are not going to text them  or to use text chat instead. The same applies to the phone discussion when you intend to discuss the issues on the phone. I don't understand your problem. Why can't you just say that you want to discuss it using [...] whatever you want? Why do you want to emphasize the importance of your voice? 

Zhest :) I think it would be better to stop chatting here.

Comment: @Humbulani Yep, we'd better stop. Tnx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To **talk it over** by phone" is one natural way of putting it, IMHO.

Of course, you might also expressly state your wish to hear the other person's voice, but I can't call to mind an established idiom for that.

> There's something I want to discuss, and the matter is important enough that I want to use the phone so that we could hear each over's voices.

Now, that's a mouthful, so I'd use "talk it over".